# Get variable values used inside a loop for outside of the loop

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file

I need to get a part of some lines(Myfile) out of the 'for' loop either into two separate variables or into an array.My goal is to use each other for constituting path of the following lines result*.txt. I write what you are seing below but it's visible that my 'a' variable is only echoing  'C:\Temp\FR'(the end of line matching token in Myfile).

Please, Is there any way to get all matching tokens in a variable/array? For example, in my case, I need to get 'C:\Temp\USA' and  'C:\Temp\FR' out of the loop for? Thanks

```
   for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%x in (Myfile) do (
   set a=%%x
  )
  echo %a%
  'MyFile
   DIR1= C:\Temp\USA
   DIR2= C:\Temp\FR
   result1.txt
   result2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal

for /f "tokens=1* delims== " %%x in (Myfile) do (
    if /i "%%x"=="dir1" set "path1=%%y"
    if /i "%%x"=="dir2" set "path2=%%y"
)

echo %path1%
echo %path2%
```

Output is:

```
C:\Temp\USA
C:\Temp\FR
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several  ways to do that. If you want read a few lines from the beginnng of the file, the easiest way is to directly read them in a couple variables:

```
< Myfile (
set /P var1=
set /P var2=
)
```

Note that these variables contain the complete lines, so it is necessary to extract the part after the equal sign.

In your example you just want the lines with equal sign, so we may use `findstr "=" Myfile` in a FOR command to just process they. If the number of lines is undefined, you must save all desired lines in an *array* as you suggested:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr "=" Myfile') do (
   set /A n+=1
   set var[!n!]=%%a
)
rem Show all array elements
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do (
   echo !var[%%i]!
)
rem Show just the second element
echo %var[2]%
```

However, in your particular case the lines you want have the form of *variable assignments*. This means that if you *execute* such lines with a SET command, the values in the lines will be "automatically" saved:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "=" Myfile') do set %%a
```

After previous FOR , you may directly get the values of `DIR1` or `DIR2` variables, for example:

```
echo %DIR1%
echo %DIR2%
```

This method is very simple and don't require any testing on the individual variables being loaded.

If you want to remove the space after the equal sign in the value, you may adjust FOR options to  do so:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims== " %%a in ('findstr "=" Myfile) do set %%a=%%b
```